# Why can't I click on submit button (91 error 438 error VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to fill out a form on an intranet page, but I can't figure out how to click on the next button.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetLTRTable()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "myurl"

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim organization As Object
    Set organization = ie.Document.all.Item("Org")
        organization.selectedindex = 0

    ie.Document.getelementsbyname("CR1").Item(1).Checked = True
    ie.Document.getelementsbyname("CR2").Item(6).Checked = True   
    ie.Document.getelementsbyname("next").Click
End Sub
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<p><input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="Action"> <input type="submit" value="Next" name="Action"> </p>
```

I am getting the following error:

> error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

or:

> error 91 "Error variable or object variable not set"

on the line `ie.Document.getelementsbyname("next").Click` wether I use `getelementsbyid` or `all.item`

[image]

Comment: I believe these functions are capital sensitive. Have you used ie.document.GetElementsByName in your code? Also, this function returns a collection of elements, since multiple elements can have the same name. If you use `ie.document.GetElementsByName("next").item(0).Click`, does that work?

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for your quick response,
Using your code I get the error 91 "Error Object variable or With block variable not set"
I did a ctrl F in the source code looking for "Next" but there is only one item called this way

Comment: I see that `next` should by with a capital N. So try if it can find `ie.document.GetElementsByName("Next").item(0).Click`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work 
Do you need further information ?

Comment: Ah.. I'm sorry I'm looking way too fast, but you could say something as well ;) The value of the element is "Next", the name of the element is "Action", and since you are searching for elements by name, you need to fill in "Action" instead of "Next". Also you have two buttons with the same name, so now you could use `item(1)` instead of `item(0)`, but you have to check that.

Comment: So much thanks Alex !
Yes well, I reckon my head is a bit blurred after the amount of time I have spent on this matter ^^.
I have another problem with the same fill form but maybe I should craete another question for it (I can't select multiple items in a dropdown list) ?
Anyway thanks again

Comment: From the modified title of the thread, I can see that your issue is solved now. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.